# Installing VMware tools fails with error:VGAuthService & Common Agent failed

Tags: debian, vmware-tools

Cannot install or upgrade VMware Tools on Debian 8.

When attempting to install it by typing `./vmware-install.pl`, then appears error:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Checking acpi hot plug                                              done
Starting VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
Switching to guest configuration:                                   done
VMware Automatic Kmods:                                             done
Guest filesystem driver:                                            done
Mounting HGFS shares:                                               done
VGAuthService:                                                     failed
Common Agent:                                                      failed
Unable to start services for VMware Tools

Execution aborted.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. uninstall prevoius Installation
   root@debian-vm:~$ vmware-uninstall-tools.pl

   2. Reinstalled Vmware Tools:

To (re)install VMware Tools, you must mount the VMware Tools CD image, extract the contents (VMware Tools), and then run the installer.

To mount the CD image and extract the contents:

```
Power on the virtual machine.
Log into the virtual machine using an account with administrator or root privileges.
Go to Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools (or VM > Install VMware Tools).

Note: If you are running the light version of Fusion, a version of Workstation without VMware Tools, or VMware Player, you are prompted to download VMware Tools before they can be installed. Click Download Now to begin the download.
Open the VMware Tools CD mounted on the desktop.
Right-click the file name that is similar to VMwareTools.x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz, click Extract to, and select the Desktop to save the extracted contents.

The vmware-tools-distrib folder is extracted to the Desktop.
```

To install VMware Tools:

```
Open a Terminal window. For more information, see Opening a command or shell prompt (1003892).
In the Terminal, run this command to navigate to the vmware-tools-distrib folder:

cd Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib
Run this command to install VMware Tools:
```

/vmware-install.pl -d

```
Note: The -d switch assumes that you want to accept the defaults. If you do not use -d, press Return to accept the defaults or supply your own answers.
Restart the virtual machine after the VMware Tools installation completes.
```

Vmware Tool Services Fail error is now gone.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help.
 I carried out the reinstallation of VMware, and did the vmware-tools reinstallation in accordance with your answer to solve the problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This solution only worked for me:

1) sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools

2) Install VMware Tools by following the usual method (Virtual Machine --> Reinstall VMWare Tools)

3) Reboot the VM

4) sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop

5) Reboot the VM, after the reboot copy/paste and drag/drop will work!

... by user 'solution101' at https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu

Comment: if you copied this from another answer, you should link to it.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who hits this issue a much simpler solution is to create the /var/run/vmware directory with 755 permissions